# How can I conditionally run a block of resources or a recipe in chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I've the following recipe used to create some users, add them to a group and set the password to expire at the first login.

```
search(:users, '*:*').each do |user|
  userPassword = "$1$scmdevop$ZDTyqia9RXSrpHGK75FjN/"
  user user['id'] do
    comment user['comment']
    home user['home']
    shell user['shell']
    manage_home true
    password "#{userPassword}"
  end

  if user['sudo'] then
    group "#{node.default["sudogroup"]}" do
      action :modify
      members user['id']
      append true
    end
  end
  if (user['resetPassword'] == nil) || (user['resetPassword']) then
    bash 'setExporation' do
      code 'chage -d 0 ' + user['id']
      user 'root'
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that in this way it will continue to reset the password and set the espiration at every run so I was trying to find how to make it conditionally. I would like to use the following command to check if the user exist

```
grep -qs #{user["id"]} /etc/passwd
```

The problem is that I can use the not_if clause only in the first resource because after that the user has been clearly created. Is there a way to get the entire block of three resources being conditional to a shell exit code?

Thanks,
Michele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is a notification from the user resource, but this might be a little hard because that would trigger on any change, not just creation. The underlying problem here is that the desired behavior you stated is expressed in procedural terms, not in terms of convergent state. Best approach is probably to build a custom resource to hide some of this logic, but at heart what you want is an `if` statement like you already have.

Comment: Will the notification trigger also if there is a if_not clause?

Comment: I can use an if clause, the problem is that I would need to set something (a property, attribute or environment variable) from a bash command in order to be checked before to call the following resources. Actually the only problem is the third resource, the expiration date, as for the user I can use a guard and the group change is ok to be reset to the initial case. Maybe should I write a custom resource for that specific behavior?

Comment: I think you are confusing the `not_if`/`only_if` guard block/string feature of Chef resources with the `if` statement which is Ruby syntax.

Comment: Well, from what I understood I can use the not_if/only_if to avoid a resource to be executed (and I'm already using it in other recipes). Isn't right?

Comment: It blocks converge actions specifically, but only on a single resource. To prevent multiple resources all at once you would just prevent them from ever compiling with a conditional.

Comment: Ok. I resolved putting a shell command run by ruby (which was the point I was missing) like this `cmd = "cat /etc/passwd | grep " + user["id"]
  userExists = \`#{cmd}\`` and then put an if clause to the entire block. Thanks!